# Como calcular a curva ROC utilizando apenas matriz de confusão

Tags: machine-learning, aprendizagem-de-máquina, métodos-estáticos

Gostaria de saber como fazer para encontrar a curva ROC tendo apenas a matriz de confusão.

```
tp = 55922
fp = 1221
fn = 1035
tn = 41812
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível. A curva ROC é calculada fazendo uma matriz de confusão para cada ponto de corte possível de um *score* contínuo.